# speed up sql, join onto two columns

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, join, multiple-columns

Good day.
I am joining onto stock on hand table based on specific date, store and article.
It seems the join is taking too long.

Only some stores will have some articles. Article 1 will only be available in store A not in B.

I know in advance that I am querying article 1 in store A, and article 2 in store B, as that is what was sold.

Rather than querying stock on hand for both articles in each store, how can I speed up the query, can I join just on specific combo A1, B2, is it possible to combine two columns in FROM table?
thanks

```
Q3_SOH AS (
  SELECT
    CONCAT(Article,"|",Site,"|",Calendar_Day) AS ID, 
    Site, 
    Article, 
    SOH_Cost, 
    SOH_Qty_EA, 
    Calendar_Day,   
     
  FROM
    `gcp-table`
  WHERE
    Calendar_Day BETWEEN DATE_ADD(startDate, INTERVAL -1 day) AND endDate
    AND Site IN (
        SELECT DISTINCT Site
        FROM  Q1)
    AND Article IN (
        SELECT DISTINCT Article
        FROM Q1))
```

hi, thanks for your help, very clever.
I am using GCP bigquery, these sections are part of WITH, Q1 gets the sales, Q3 is for stock on hand.
Then joining and writing calculated fields is relatively easy. This SOH table is a massive database.
Joining this way its seems is not an improvement, as I am still joining all articles to all stores.
I believe articles exists in all stores, but quantity is zero for most.
We can have the same article multiple times.
Could I write something like

```
in Q1 CONCAT(Site, Article) as ID



SELECT 
 site, article, soh_cost, soh_qty, date, 
 concat(site, article) AS ID
FROM 'gcp-b'
WHERE
concat(site, article) in DISTINCT(Q1.ID)
```

Original seems fastest.
The least time taken.

Comment: I have added a tag for MySQL - I assume this is the platform you are using?

Comment: You haven't posted a complete query. Please post the complete query, indicate table sizes and indexes, and ideally include a query plan.

Comment: `IN (SELECT DISTINCT...)` can sometimes be rewritten as `WHERE EXISTS` to gain performance improvements, but it depends on your current query plan and indexes

Comment: Is something missing?  I don't recognize this syntax: `Q3_SOH AS (`.

Comment: Both Site and Article are coming from Q1?  Yet you don't what them paired up?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a join for the same effect

```
  SELECT
    CONCAT(Article,"|",Site,"|",B.Calendar_Day) AS ID, 
    B.Site, 
    B.Article, 
    B.SOH_Cost, 
    B.SOH_Qty_EA, 
    B.Calendar_Day
  FROM `gcp-table` as B
  JOIN Q1 as QS ON B.Site = QS.Site
  JOIN Q1 as QA ON B.Article = QA.Article
  WHERE  Calendar_Day BETWEEN DATE_ADD(startDate, INTERVAL -1 day) AND endDate
```

Note that if Site or article appears more than once in Q1 then do it like this:

```
  SELECT
    CONCAT(Article,"|",Site,"|",B.Calendar_Day) AS ID, 
    B.Site, 
    B.Article, 
    B.SOH_Cost, 
    B.SOH_Qty_EA, 
    B.Calendar_Day
  FROM `gcp-table` as B
  JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT SITE FROM Q1) as QS ON B.Site = QS.Site
  JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT ARTICLE FROM Q1) as QA ON B.Article = QA.Article
  WHERE  Calendar_Day BETWEEN DATE_ADD(startDate, INTERVAL -1 day) AND endDate
```